# How to use an other component to trigger the p:fileUpload choose button?

Tags: primefaces

It shows file upload button and graphic image separately but I want when I click on the graphic image it uploads the file.

Here is my code for file upload:

```html
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{pmController.handleFileUpload}"
    mode="advanced" label="Upload" update="messages" auto="true">
    <h:graphicImage name="images/AddImage.gif" style="margin-left: 1%;"
        title="Attach Image" />
</p:fileUpload>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is adding a style class to your upload component and use that to select and click the choose button when you click on the graphic image. Although PrimeFaces allows you to use the graphic image in the `p:fileUpload` I would not do so. It could very well lead to unexpected / unintended behavior.

```html
<p:fileUpload styleClass="myUpload"
              .../>
<h:graphicImage ...
                onclick="document.querySelector('.myUpload input').click()"/>
```

If you want to hide the `p:fileUpload` "Choose" button, add the following CSS rule:

```css
.myUpload .ui-fileupload-choose { display: none; }
```

Comment: <p:fileUpload styleClass="myUpload" process="@this"
fileUploadListener="#{wctController.handleFileUpload}"
 update="messages" auto="true" />

<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

Comment: <h:graphicImage name="images/AddImage.gif" process="@this"
       onclick="document.querySelector('.myUpload input').click()"
style="margin-left: 1%;" title="Attach Image" />

Comment: I'm using this code so please tell me how to remove the choose button of primefaces.

Comment: <p:fileUpload styleClass="myUpload" process="@this" fileUploadListener="#{wctController.handleFileUpload}" update="messages" auto="true" />

Comment: <h:graphicImage name="images/AddImage.gif" process="@this" onclick="document.querySelector('.myUpload input').click()" style="margin-left: 1%;" title="Attach Image" />

Comment: I'm using this code it shows the choose button and graphic image so please tell me how to remove the choose button of primefaces.